# How to implement this dynamic select options in view using "select_tag"?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have two model objects which are `Event` and `Task` , they have **one-to-many** association.

Event model:

```
class Event < ActiveRecord
  has_many :Task
```

Task model:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord
  belongs_to :Event
```

My controller has a index function which return the list of events (@events), **Maybe** return also a list of tasks(@tasks):

```
class MyController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @events = Event.all
    @tasks.....

  end
```

In my view (index.html.haml), I have defined a multi-select field for all **events** in a table column as below:

```
%td
  =select_tag('events',options_from_collection_for_select(@events, 'id', 'name'), {:multiple=>'multiple'})
```

the output code of the above select_tag is:

```
<td>
<select id="events" multiple="multiple" name="events">
    <option value="1">Event 1</option>
    <option value="2">Event 2 </option>
</select>
</td>
```

What I want is in another table column I have another multi-select field for **tasks** which looks just like the **events** multi-select field, **BUT the key feature is that**, the content of the **tasks** select options is dynamically changed based on which **event or events** user selected from the **events** multi-select field.

For example, suppose event_1 is associated with task_1 and task_2, if user mouse click on event_1, the tasks multi-select field will show task_1 and task_2 as options which is available for user to select next.

How to implement this feature in rails? I am using Rails 3. I guess this feature needs some ajax magic to play, but I have no idea how to implement it, it is better if someone can give a simple example on this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this example is exactly what you need for your models
http://pullmonkey.com/2008/03/30/dynamic-select-boxes-ruby-on-rails/.

And I would recommend you to keep a logic for your models.What I mean is

```
 class Event < ActiveRecord
     has_many :tasks # also notice...no capital "t"
 end
```

Same for Task model